# (what I suspect is a very simple) q about Cursor For Loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Just learning PL/SQL and Oracle SQL Developer, and still coming to terms with the syntax a little bit. I've created a select statement and a Cursor For Loop. The select statement retrieves a bunch of things, including AVG(USAGE), which I'm writing inserting into a different table.

Mostly not a problem, but I can't figure out the syntax for inserting the AVG(USAGE) in the INSERT statement.

---

```
v_dayNumber NUMBER;

CURSOR c_nonPublicHoliday is SELECT STREET, SUBURB, DAY, AVG(VOLUME)
                             FROM RAW_TABLE, HOLIDAYS
                             WHERE  to_char(day, 'd') = v_dayNumber
                             AND RAW_TABLE IN (SELECT HOLIDAY_DATE FROM HOLIDAYS)
                             GROUP BY STREET, SUBURB, DAY
                             ORDER BY DAY;

BEGIN

FOR v_forecastDay IN 1..14 LOOP

    v_dayNumber := v_forecastDay;

    FOR R1 IN c_nonPublicHoliday LOOP

    INSERT INTO LOCAL_TABLE(STREET,SUBURB,DAY)
    VALUES (R1.STREET, R1.SUBURB, R1.DAY);

  END LOOP;

END LOOP;

END;
```

Essentially all I'm doing is cycling through the next 14 days and retrieving historical average usage for that day of the week (I know by itself, seven days would achieve the same, but there's other things going on). Just need to then write that average into this LOCAL_TABLE, but I'm not sure of the syntax required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is possible to refer to the computed average without providing an alias in the query, that produces code that is quite unreadable and hard to maintain.  Realistically, you want to add an alias in your query (`avg_volume` in this case)

```
CURSOR c_nonPublicHoliday is SELECT STREET, SUBURB, DAY, AVG(VOLUME) avg_volume
```

and then use that alias in your `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO LOCAL_TABLE(STREET, SUBURB, DAY, AVG_VOLUME)
VALUES (R1.STREET, R1.SUBURB, R1.DAY, r1.avg_volume);
```